# Mac application crashes unexpectedly with Exception Type: EXC_ARITHMETIC (SIGFPE)

Tags: macos, xcode4.2

I am new to MAC development and i recently created a mac application. My application works fine on MAC OS 10.7.2 but it crashes on OS 10.7.3. Initially, application was working fine but after i upgraded my OS version, it started crashing with crash log exception:

```
    Exception Type:  EXC_ARITHMETIC (SIGFPE)
    Exception Codes: EXC_I386_DIV (divide by zero)
    Application Specific Information:
objc[4541]: garbage collection is OFF

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.paragoni.sp                0x000000010002674b -[MyWindowController populateImportedTracksArray] + 1067 (MyWindowController.m:6363)
1   com.paragoni.sp                0x000000010000ce96 -[MyWindowController awakeFromNib] + 7476 (MyWindowController.m:500)
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff87665021 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 49
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff87664fa2 -[NSSet makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 274
4   com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8e4bfb2f -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 1245
5   com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8e4b609f loadNib + 322
6   com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8e4b559c +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 217
7   com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8e4b54b7 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibFile:externalNameTable:withZone:] + 141
8   com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8e4b53fa +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 364
9   com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8e7289b3 NSApplicationMain + 398
10  com.paragoni.sp                0x0000000100001dac 0x100000000 + 7596
```

I am unable to understand the error reason. Is this error coming due to bugs in my code or might be due to my upgrade. Please guide me...

Comment: So have you stepped through the code under the debugger to identify the line that's causing "divide by zero"?  Do you have a "/" (or equivalent) anywhere in the relevant code?  A stack traceback is of little/no use without the code!

Comment: OK i will study the code and try to find the line causing error... Thankx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a division by zero on line 6363 of the file `MyWindowController.m`.

The Exception Code clearly states "divide by zero", and the top of the callstack tells you the exact location where it happened (when the source file is known, it is displayed in the format "filename:linenumber").

Comment: "divide by zero" <- Thank you for this.